# Does metal conduit need to be continuous to function as the ground conductor?

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to add a ground to the existing garage sub panel (240v, three conductor) while burying the elevated wires. I hope to use rigid steel conduit as the ground, but can't run it back to the main panel. Does the conduit have to be continuous to the main panel, or can it be run from a box grounded by a wire conductor?

I hope to run the existing wires (2-2-4) through a new metal junction box located inside the house - the through the rigid galvanized conduit to the detached garage. The panel is 50A. I hoped to supply ground to the junction box through a conductor from the main to the junction box lug. I can’t dig near the main due to septic/graywater systems, and the conduit I already have (1”) won’t accept more conductors.

Comment: Is the box you want to use metal or plastic, and do you plan to put it inside a finished space, inside a unfinished space, or outside?  What size wires are you running for the new feeder, for that matter?

Comment: I hope to run the existing wires (2-2-4) through a new metal junction box located inside the house - the through the rigid galvanized conduit to the detached garage. The panel is 50A. I hoped to supply ground to the junction box through a conductor from the main to the junction box lug. I can’t dig near the main due to septic/graywater systems, and the conduit I already have (1”) won’t accept more conductors. Thanks

Comment: I take it the panel this circuit is fed from is outside, by the way?  Also, are you planning to put the junction box in a room with finished walls, or in an unfinished space with bare concrete/... walls, such as an unfinished basement? (This matters for specifying the correct box)

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Maybe reference this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194126/using-steel-conduit-as-a-ground-intermitantly-any-problems-with-this

Comment: And this one: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194126/using-steel-conduit-as-a-ground-intermitantly-any-problems-with-this

Answer (score -1):

Metal conduit has to be continuous, as the earth cable is tied to it on both ends, which is then connected to the main earthing terminal back at the switch board.

Comment: Hi,I either can't understand your answer,or it doesn't actually answer the question. OP's question is whether conduit used as ground has to be continuous all the way to the panel,or if it's legal to run a cable with a ground wire from the panel to a metal junction box (to it's ground screw) and then continue with conduit-as-ground from there on.